# Get Data from another collection (string -> ObjectId)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-realm

Let's say I have these two collections:

```
// Members:
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"60dca71f0394f430c8ca296d"
    },
    "church":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b",
    "name":"Julio Verne Cerqueira"
},
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"60dca71f0394f430c8ca29a8"
    },
    "nome":"Ryan Steel Oliveira",
    "church":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6c"
}
```

And

```
// Churches
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6c"
    },
    "name": "Saint Antoine Hill",
    "active": true
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b"
    },
    "name": "Jackeline Hill",
    "active": true
}
```

And I want to query it and have a result like this:

```
// Member with Church names
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"60dca71f0394f430c8ca296d"
    },
    "church":"Jackeline Hill",
    "name":"Julio Verne Cerqueira"
},
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"60dca71f0394f430c8ca29a8"
    },
    "church":"Saint Antoine Hill",
    "nome":"Ryan Steel Oliveira"
}
```

If I try a Lookup, I have the following Result: (It is getting the entire churches collection).
[image]

**How would I do the query, so it gives me only the one church that member is related to?**

**And, if possible, how to Sort the result in alphabetical order by church then by name?**

**Obs.:** MongoDB Version: 4.4.10

Comment: FYI, I removed `angular` and `angular-material` tags since the question doesn't related with them, it is more to be `mongodb` question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is matching error in the `$lookup` --> `$pipeline` --> `$match`.

It should be:

```
$match: {
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      "$_id",
      "$$searchId"
    ]
  }
}
```

From the provided documents, `members` to `churchies` relationship will be **1 to many**. Hence, when you join `members` with `churchies` via `$lookup`, the output `church` will be an array with **only one `churchies` document**.

---

Aggregation pipelines:

1. `$lookup` - Join `members` collection (by `$$searchId`) with `churchies` (by `_id`).
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `church` array field to multiple documents.
3. `$project` - Decorate output document.
4. `$sort` - Sort by `church` and `name` ascending.

```
db.members.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "churchies",
      "let": {
        searchId: {
          "$toObjectId": "$church"
        }
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$searchId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            name: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "church"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$church"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      church: "$church.name",
      name: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "church": 1,
      "name": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RL2reJ_0mi1)

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was in need.